# Retrieve Social Feed list based on count REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, newsfeed

I am using REST API to retrieve social feed list from app web.

```
appweburl + "/_api/social.feed/my/timelinefeed(MaxThreadCount=10)"
```

This URL get list successfully with limit 10. I am having show more post option and my question is how can I retrieve list by clicking show more option in the order of 0 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30,.....How Can I achieve this?